# Are HTML Entities inherently unsafe?

Tags: html, owasp

When submitting HTML that contains entities to the OWASP [HTMLSanitzer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project), entities are converted.

For example:

```
BEFORE: <p>blah blah blah &diams;</p>
```

The resulting HTML ends up looking like this:

```
AFTER: <p>blah blah blah ?</p>
```

The entity is converted back to it's original unicode character.

Why does OWASP do that? Are entities unsafe?  For me, having the entities solves any issues down the road with unicode text.

Additionally, is there a way to allow the entities to remain untouched in HTMLSanitzer?

Comment: No, they’re not unsafe, but they’re generally unnecessary. If you need entities to remain untouched, what you generally really need is to fix your encoding.

Comment: I don't see any methods in OWASP that take the encoding character set. Do you?

Comment: What do you mean? Assuming they accept and produce Unicode strings, you’ll be encoding to UTF-8 after they’re done.

Comment: The app is international. I don't think I can force UTF-8. The submitted text may be a different character set. That's why we use entities.

Comment: It doesn’t matter what the submitted text is; just serve UTF-8. The sanitizer, as you said, decodes the entities for you.

Comment: Er, no. <p>blah blah blah â™¦</p>  Basically this the sanitizer is returning invalid HTML and it's a bug.

Comment: No, it sounds like you’re not returning UTF-8. Do you have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag? Are you encoding your output as UTF-8?

Comment: This is a bug:https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/issues/detail?id=30

Comment: Just because somebody reports it as a bug doesn’t mean that it’s a bug. Once again, please make sure that you are sending a response with consistent encoding. (`<meta charset="utf-8" />` should do the trick.) `â™¦` is what you would get if you responded with UTF-8 and the browser (due to lack of a specified encoding, which you *always* need – this is actually a security issue) assumed it was ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score -1):

They are safe,  but is very good practice escape or convert them

This will allow you avoid being:

- script injected
- Face a browser text incompatibility ( have you seen    those sites
  with unicode like chars? )

And Probably more

See it as a standard way to represent a text as it should be in different languages and codifications,  like some strict  utf8 will show a bad formatted text if you don't escape them, because some special chars with acute or tilde, etc will be not recognizable  to the end user when showed up.

Comment: It's a bug. Valid HTML should include the entities over having to use any particular encoding. The sanitizer should not alter entities or the Policy should have an option around it.

Comment: @sproketboy: You don’t have to use any particular encoding. UTF-8 is just the best one.

Comment: agree with @minitech, UTF-8 is the best for me, but sadly you don't store everywhere as utf8